# apache + varnish + cloudflare Log IP's

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish, cloudflare

trying to log the real ip of the visitors to a site, with a server running apache, varnish and cloudflare.

im currently logging the cloudflare server IP's from visitors, after altering the default.vcl file to recorording incoming requests after report 127.0.0.1 using the code below.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # Add a unique header containing the client address
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  set    req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

}
```

Also altering the log format.

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" varnishcombined
```

i also installed mod_clouflare but i just received the cloudflare IP's not the true visitors.

i've seen workarounds for NGINX, but not Apache.

Comment: I don't work with CloudFlare, but in our setup `LB -> Varnish -> Apache`, the LB stores the client's IP, and passes on in a variable called "ClientIP" (or could be "X-Forwarded-For"), and that is visible to Varnish as `req.http.ClientIP` and as `%{ClientIP}` to Apache.

Comment: technically it should work as mod_cloudflare without varnish installed will pass the correct ip to the logs, so i assume something is going wrong between cloudflare and varnish, not capturing..

Comment: A combination of `varnishlog` and `std` can help. Atop your vcl, insert `import std;` next, in `vcl_deliver`, use `std.log ("Client IP is: " + req.http.NameOfClientIPVariable);` restart varnish or reload configs. Run `varnishlog`, make http calls to your app, and look for the "Client IP is: ___" -- there can be lots of output, especially if this is a busy server.

Comment: Fixed it.

instead of using varnish variables to capture the ip

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" varnishcombined
changing the x=forwarded-for to what mod_cloudflare uses to hold the origional ip. (CF-Connecting-IP)

LogFormat "%{CF-Connecting-IP}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}